# Change color of every div element with the same class if another element is equals some text

Tags: javascript, html, css

If the text in `myDiv`equals string "Hello", the background color of every div element with `myDiv` class change to blue. I want to modify this javascript code that if in `myDiv` class will be string "Hello" every class with name `changedcolor` will change its background color to blue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="myDIV">
Hello
</div>
<div class="changedcolor">
Bye
</div>


<div class="myDIV">
Hello
</div>
<div class="changedcolor">
Bye
</div>

<script>

var targets = document.getElementsByClassName('myDIV');
for( var i in targets ) {
if (targets[i].innerHTML.indexOf("Hello") != -1) {
    targets[i].className='myDIV blue';
}  
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

this is in style.css:

```
 .blue { background-color: blue; }
```

Comment: Not getting what you mean.

Comment: If the text in myDiv will equals Hello, I want to change background color of every div with class "changedcolor". Now it is changing color of myDiv class.

Comment: i think it is not so simple.

Comment: Can you change document.getElementsByClassName('myDIV'); to document.getElementsByClassName('changedcolor');?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, if I understand you correctly, but you can try following code, which adds class 'blue' to every element with class 'changedcolor', if there is at least one element containing 'Hello'. (I do not change the color of the 'Hello'-element now.

This is the vanilla JavaScript version. You could (and should) do this with jQuery, as mentioned by Karamell.

```js
var targets = document.getElementsByClassName('myDIV');
var foundHello = false;

for (var i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
  // Plain Javascript
  if (targets[i].innerHTML.indexOf("Hello") != -1) {
    elementList = targets[i].querySelectorAll('.changedcolor');
    
    for (var j = 0; j < elementList.length; j++) {
       elementList[j].className = 'changedColor blue';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="myDIV">
    Hello
    <div class="changedcolor">Bye</div>
  </div>
  <div class="myDIV">
    These are not the druids you are looking for.
    <div class="changedcolor">See you later</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: is it possible to somehow modify this code that if in the second myDiv will be another text than hello, it will not change the color of second div "changedcolor". Maybe stick the class changedcolor inside the myDiv? Do you understand me? I want to change only the color of class where the text Hello will be.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier, more readable, and good practice to select through [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) instead getElementsByClassName.

```
var targets = $('.myDIV');

targets.each(function( index, element ) {
    if(element.innerHTML.indexOf("Hello") != -1) {
        $('.changedcolor').css('background-color','blue');
        $(element).addClass('blue');
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to use `$('.changedcolor')`, or your code will not add the style-attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on when you wish to trigger this action. You can use the following code to do this when the page loads:

window.onload = function(){

*then do you code here but replace "myDIV blue" with "blue" as in the css class name.*